# How to upload image in React Native with NodeJs?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, react-native, express, react-native-image-picker

This is my frontend:

```
import React from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, Text, View, TouchableHighlight } from 'react-native';
import {launchImageLibrary} from 'react-native-image-picker';



const App = () => {
  
  const [photo, setPhoto] = React.useState(null);

  const handleChoosePhoto = () => {
    launchImageLibrary({ maxHeight:300, maxWidth:300 }, (response) => {
      // console.log(response);
      if (response) {
        setPhoto(response);
      }
    });
  };
  const handleUploadPhoto = () => {
    const data = new FormData();
    data.append('photo', {
      name: photo.fileName,
      type: photo.type,
      uri: photo.uri,
    });
    console.log(data);
    fetch('http://172.20.10.2:5000/upload_profile_picture/', {
      method: 'POST',
      headers : {
        'Accept' : 'application/json',
        'Content-Type' : 'multipart/form-data'
      },
      body: data
      // body : JSON.stringify({ userId: '123' })
    })
      .then((response) => response.json())
      .then((response) => {
        console.log('response', response);
      })
      .catch((error) => {
        console.log('error', error);
      });
  };
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <TouchableHighlight
      onPress={handleChoosePhoto}
      >
        <Text>Choose image</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
      <TouchableHighlight onPress={handleUploadPhoto}>
        <Text>Upload Image</Text>
      </TouchableHighlight>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
 container : {
   flex:1,
   justifyContent:"center",
   alignItems:"center"
 }
});

export default App;
```

this is my backend:

```
const express = require("express");
const app = express();
const jwt = require('jsonwebtoken');
require("./conn");
const multer = require('multer');
const members = require("./models/members");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000;


app.use(express.json());

const storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, './images/');
    },
    filename: (req, file, callback) => {
      callback(null, `${file.fieldname}_${Date.now()}_${file.originalname}`);
    },
  });
  const upload = multer({ storage }).single('file');



  app.post("/upload_profile_picture", upload, (req, res) => {
    console.log('file', req.file);
    console.log('body', req.body);
    res.status(200).json({
      message: 'success!',
    });
  });
app.listen(PORT, () => {
    console.log("Port is working.");
})
```

I am getting this output in react native terminal:

```
{"_parts": [["photo", [Object]]]}
 LOG  error [TypeError: Network request failed]
```

**But nothing is getting in nodeJs (Express Server)**

I didn't found any tutorial or youtube video regarding this. Or if you can do this with **"React-native-image-crop-picker"** All would be fine. Thanks in advance.